# How do I call C++/CLI source from JavaProject

Tags: java, c++-cli

A Java programm relies on functionality which needs to be implemented by C++/CLI project too. Since I don't like to implement and maintain this functionality for both programming languages, I'm searching for a way to just write this source once.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote examples yesterday evening covering the implementation to and from C++.
http://csharphardcoreprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/03/25/java-to-c-day-15-professional-call-c-from-java-call-java-from-c/ .
You need the Java Native Interface (JNI).